# SCP says file has downloaded, but the file does not appear

Tags: macos, shell, ssh, terminal

I am using ssh to work on a remote server, however when I try to download a file using scp in this format:

```
scp name@website.com:somefile.zip ~/Desktop
```

It asks me for my password, and shows this:

```
somefile.zip                                      100% 6491     6.3KB/s   00:00
```

however, this file never appears on my desktop. Any help

Answer (score 8):

I think that you are logging into the remote machine using ssh and then running the command on the remote machine. You should actually be running the command without logging into your remote server first.

Comment: Incorrect.  Please delete this "answer" before you hurt someone.

Comment: Well, this was my problem... this can be helpful for clueless people like me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the file path

```
scp name@website.com:/path/to/somefile.zip ~/Desktop
```

Comment: i have it as the specific path, but upon further inspection, it makes a file in my home directory called ~/Desktop. No clue why

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake is to try it with the session started in the server, this would cause the download to be done inside the same server therefore I recommend you to open a new console without logging in to the server and execute the following command:

```bash
scp name@website.com:/path/to/file.zip ~/Desktop
```

**Note:** Remember to include the complete file path.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar problem and was completely unable to resolve it. It was creating files in the remote machine with a name matching the path I was trying to save to on my local machine. I recommend just using WinSCP. Much more intuitive UI and I didn't have this problem there.

Answer (score 0):

`~/Desktop` should actually be a directory, not a file. I suggest that you do the following:

1. Remove the `~/Desktop` file with `rm ~/Desktop` (or move it with `mv` if you want to keep its contents).
2. Create the directory with `mkdir ~/Desktop`.
3. Try again to `scp` the zip file.

BTW, when I need to copy files into directories, I usually put a slash after the directory to avoid such problems (in case I make a mistake), e.g. `scp server:file ~/Desktop/`; if the directory doesn't exist, I get an error instead of unwanted file creation.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this from a command line, and you have a working directory for that command line (on your local machine), this is the directory that your file will be downloaded to.  The final argument in your command is only what you want the name of the file to be.  So, first, change directory to where you want the file to land.  I'm doing this from git bash on a Windows machine, so it looks like this:

```
cd C:\Users\myUserName\Downloads
```

Now that I have my working directory where I want the file to go:

```
scp -i 'c:\Users\myUserName\.ssh\AWSkeyfile.pem' ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/ec2-user/IwantThisFile.tar IgotThisFile.tar
```

Or, in your case, (that is with the VERY strong password you must be using):

```
cd ~/Desktop
scp name@website.com:/path/to/somefile.zip somefile.zip
```